# Cron job not executing a PHP file

Tags: php, cron

I recently added a cron job to execute a PHP file daily, but the database is not being updated as it should be in the PHP file. I'm assuming this is because the cron job is not running.

Here is what I put for the cronjob :

```
  @daily /etc/cron.php (located by executing crontab -l)

  -- php file --
  $db = new PDO("dsn", "username", "password");
  $db->exec("UPDATE subscriptions SET exp_date = exp_date - 1 WHERE payment_status = 'Completed'");
```

The field exp_date is set to 32 whenever a user makes a purchase, but it's not being subtracted by 1 via the cronjob I have in place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if your script runs fine in console, with `php /etc/cron.php`, if you have some path using for example `$_SERVER` var you will get errors.

Comment: it did work though after checking the database

Comment: did you add `php` before the command in the crontab? `@daily php /etc/cron.php`

Comment: oh it has to be like @daily php /etc/cron.php ?

Comment: Yes, where "php" should be the executable of php, it might be in `/usr/bin/php`, otherwise the crontab will try to execute as unix command

Comment: I ran php /etc/cron.php and it executed fine, so I am assuming also that if I put @daily php /etc/cron.php it would work as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, anyways try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `crontab -e` and try with following code.

```
0 0 * * *  <path>/php /etc/cron.php
```

This will run in everyday 00:00, and you should give the proper path to php (sample : `/usr/bin/php5`)

Note : Assume that your file is running well in CLI.

If not tr with following permission and try again.

```
chmod a+x /etc/cron.php
```